# How to insert value of multiple select checkbox into database

Tags: php

I have a multiple select checkbox but i couldnt find a way on how to insert into database which each checkbox will create new rows in database.

[this is how my dropdown looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCnGR.jpg)

```
 <select id="plant" name="plant[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
        <?php 
                    $query_plant = "SELECT * FROM plant WHERE plant_enable=1 ORDER BY plant_name";
                    $rs_plant = DB_Query($query_plant);

                    while ($row_plant = DB_FetchRow($rs_plant)) {

                        $plant.='<option name='.$row_plant["plant_shortname"].' value='.$row_plant["plant_id"].'>' .$row_plant["plant_name"].' ['.$row_plant["plant_id"].']</option>';

                        }   

                    mysql_free_result($rs_plant);
                    echo $plant;
                ?>
      </select>
```

Comment: is this an abandoned question?

Comment: i just posted the answer. sorry as im still new to this page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if(isset($_POST['company'])) {

```
            $checkbox1 = $_POST['plant']; 
            $chk="";
            $stf_sql = "SELECT * FROM test_plant WHERE staff_id = '".$STAFF_ID."'";
            $stf_res = DB_Query($stf_sql);

            if(DB_RowsReturned($stf_res) > 0) {
               $del_sql = "DELETE FROM test_plant WHERE staff_id = '".$STAFF_ID."'";
               $del_res = DB_Query($del_sql);
            } 

            foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
            {  
               $in_ch="insert into test_plant(staff_id, plant_name, submit_dt) values ('$STAFF_ID','$chk1', Now())";  
               $in_res = DB_Query($in_ch);

                 $abc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_plant");

               while($abc_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($abc)) {
                   foreach($abc_row as $key => $value) {
                       echo $key;
                   }

               }

            }

        } else {
            echo "OK";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected checkbox value by using the name of checkbox on form submit like:

```
$plants = $_REQUEST['plant'];
```

`$plants` is an array here, so use `foreach()` to iterate over it and for each value make a insert query or combine all values in a single query and fire that query on database.